# How to get IST date time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss) in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

The below code gave me IST time date

```
const x=new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '')
```

Output:
2020-09-01 17:49:48

I want to get IST time instead of UTC which is

```
2020-09-01 23:20:48
```

How to get above output in node js.

Comment: `toISOString()` will give you the output in UTC. Consider using `moment.js` if you want time in specific timezones.

Comment: Second on using `moment.js`, will save a lot of headaches when working with timezones.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava how to get using moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install moment package and write the following two lines code to solve the problem:

```
var moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 4):

- Consider using this:

```js
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'})
```

Comment: give correct date time but format is different. Can you help to get format mentioned in the question?

Comment: You can convert it to 24 hr format using `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata', hour12: false})` . After that treat it as a string and format it the way you want.

Comment: time is fine now thanks but date is creating issue. Need in format YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS.